# How to plot caret metrics performance?

Tags: r

Under R , I need to plot classification performance curves :

The `conf_matrices` is a list that contains several caret `confusionMatrix` outputs. Each element of the list represent the performance of an epoch. The number of elements is number of training epochs.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)


plot_classification_performance <- function(conf_matrices, output_directory = "plots", plot_title = "Classification Performance Evolution", y_label = "Value", x_label = "Epoch") {
      if (!dir.exists(output_directory)) {
        dir.create(output_directory)
      }
   


  class_names <- rownames(conf_matrices[[1]]$table)
  
  for (class_name in class_names) {
    metrics_data <- data.frame(Epoch = numeric(), Accuracy = numeric(), Sensitivity = numeric(), Specificity = numeric(), Pos_Pred_Value = numeric(), Neg_Pred_Value = numeric(), Precision = numeric(), Recall = numeric(), F1 = numeric(), Balanced_Accuracy = numeric())
    
    for (i in seq_along(conf_matrices)) {
      cm <- conf_matrices[[i]]
      
      print(paste("Class Name: ", class_name))
      print(paste("Row Names: ", rownames(cm$byClass)))
      
      class_index <- which(rownames(cm$byClass) == paste("Class:", class_name))
      
      print(paste("Class Index: ", class_index))
      
      metrics <- data.frame(
        Epoch = i,
        Accuracy = cm$overall['Accuracy'],
        Sensitivity = cm$byClass[class_index, 'Sensitivity'],
        Specificity = cm$byClass[class_index, 'Specificity'],
        Pos_Pred_Value = cm$byClass[class_index, 'Pos Pred Value'],
        Neg_Pred_Value = cm$byClass[class_index, 'Neg Pred Value'],
        Precision = cm$byClass[class_index, 'Precision'],
        Recall = cm$byClass[class_index, 'Recall'],
        F1 = cm$byClass[class_index, 'F1'],
        Balanced_Accuracy = cm$byClass[class_index, 'Balanced Accuracy']
      )
      
      metrics_data <- rbind(metrics_data, metrics)
    }
    
    df_melted <- melt(metrics_data, id.vars = "Epoch")
    
    p <- ggplot(df_melted, aes(x = Epoch, y = value, color = variable, group = variable)) +
      geom_smooth(se = FALSE, method = "loess") + # Add smoothed line
      labs(y = y_label, x = x_label, title = paste(plot_title, "-", class_name)) +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
      scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set3") + # Use a color palette that is easy to distinguish
      guides(colour = guide_legend(nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)) +
      geom_text(data = df_melted[df_melted$Epoch == min(df_melted$Epoch), ], aes(label = paste0(variable, " (", 1:length(unique(variable)), ")")), hjust = -0.1, vjust = 0.5)
    
    print(p)
    
    ggsave(filename = file.path(output_directory, paste0("plot_", gsub(" ", "_", class_name), ".png")), plot = p)
  }
}

plot_classification_performance(iris_test[[3]], "C:/Users/mouad/Desktop/MOUAD/Article-2/images", "Classification performance", "Value", "N_epochs")
```

This works as expected because iris has 3 classes.

However , i'm facing following error with a binary classes such as ballons :

```
plot_classification_performance(ballons_test[[3]], "C:/Users/mouad/Desktop/MOUAD/Article-2/images", "Classification performance", "Value", "N_epochs")
    
    [1] "Class Name:  FALSE"
    [1] "Row Names:  "
    [1] "Class Index:  "
    Error in cm$byClass[class_index, "Sensitivity"] : 
      incorrect number of dimensions
    Called from: data.frame(Epoch = i, Accuracy = cm$overall["Accuracy"], Sensitivity = cm$byClass[class_index, 
        "Sensitivity"], Specificity = cm$byClass[class_index, "Specificity"], 
        Pos_Pred_Value = cm$byClass[class_index, "Pos Pred Value"], 
        Neg_Pred_Value = cm$byClass[class_index, "Neg Pred Value"], 
        Precision = cm$byClass[class_index, "Precision"], Recall = cm$byClass[class_index, 
            "Recall"], F1 = cm$byClass[class_index, "F1"], Balanced_Accuracy = cm$byClass[class_index, 
            "Balanced Accuracy"])

The used data : 



    dput(ballons_test[[3]])
list(structure(list(positive = "FALSE", table = structure(c(12L, 
0L, 0L, 7L), dim = c(2L, 2L), dimnames = list(Prediction = c("FALSE", 
"TRUE"), Reference = c("FALSE", "TRUE")), class = "table"), overall = c(Accuracy = 1, 
Kappa = 1, AccuracyLower = 0.823533088193035, AccuracyUpper = 1, 
AccuracyNull = 0.631578947368421, AccuracyPValue = 0.000161482422830051, 
McnemarPValue = NaN), byClass = c(Sensitivity = 1, Specificity = 1, 
`Pos Pred Value` = 1, `Neg Pred Value` = 1, Precision = 1, Recall = 1, 
F1 = 1, Prevalence = 0.631578947368421, `Detection Rate` = 0.631578947368421, 
`Detection Prevalence` = 0.631578947368421, `Balanced Accuracy` = 1
), mode = "sens_spec", dots = list()), class = "confusionMatrix"), 
    structure(list(positive = "FALSE", table = structure(c(12L, 
    0L, 0L, 7L), dim = c(2L, 2L), dimnames = list(Prediction = c("FALSE", 
    "TRUE"), Reference = c("FALSE", "TRUE")), class = "table"), 
        overall = c(Accuracy = 1, Kappa = 1, AccuracyLower = 0.823533088193035, 
        AccuracyUpper = 1, AccuracyNull = 0.631578947368421, 
        AccuracyPValue = 0.000161482422830051, McnemarPValue = NaN
        ), byClass = c(Sensitivity = 1, Specificity = 1, `Pos Pred Value` = 1, 
        `Neg Pred Value` = 1, Precision = 1, Recall = 1, F1 = 1, 
        Prevalence = 0.631578947368421, `Detection Rate` = 0.631578947368421, 
        `Detection Prevalence` = 0.631578947368421, `Balanced Accuracy` = 1
        ), mode = "sens_spec", dots = list()), class = "confusionMatrix"), 
    structure(list(positive = "FALSE", table = structure(c(12L, 
    0L, 0L, 7L), dim = c(2L, 2L), dimnames = list(Prediction = c("FALSE", 
    "TRUE"), Reference = c("FALSE", "TRUE")), class = "table"), 
        overall = c(Accuracy = 1, Kappa = 1, AccuracyLower = 0.823533088193035, 
        AccuracyUpper = 1, AccuracyNull = 0.631578947368421, 
        AccuracyPValue = 0.000161482422830051, McnemarPValue = NaN
        ), byClass = c(Sensitivity = 1, Specificity = 1, `Pos Pred Value` = 1, 
        `Neg Pred Value` = 1, Precision = 1, Recall = 1, F1 = 1, 
        Prevalence = 0.631578947368421, `Detection Rate` = 0.631578947368421, 
        `Detection Prevalence` = 0.631578947368421, `Balanced Accuracy` = 1
        ), mode = "sens_spec", dots = list()), class = "confusionMatrix"), 
    structure(list(positive = "FALSE", table = structure(c(12L, 
    0L, 0L, 7L), dim = c(2L, 2L), dimnames = list(Prediction = c("FALSE", 
    "TRUE"), Reference = c("FALSE", "TRUE")), class = "table"), 
        overall = c(Accuracy = 1, Kappa = 1, AccuracyLower = 0.823533088193035, 
        AccuracyUpper = 1, AccuracyNull = 0.631578947368421, 
        AccuracyPValue = 0.000161482422830051, McnemarPValue = NaN
        ), byClass = c(Sensitivity = 1, Specificity = 1, `Pos Pred Value` = 1, 
        `Neg Pred Value` = 1, Precision = 1, Recall = 1, F1 = 1, 
        Prevalence = 0.631578947368421, `Detection Rate` = 0.631578947368421, 
        `Detection Prevalence` = 0.631578947368421, `Balanced Accuracy` = 1
        ), mode = "sens_spec", dots = list()), class = "confusionMatrix"), 
    structure(list(positive = "FALSE", table = structure(c(12L, 
    0L, 0L, 7L), dim = c(2L, 2L), dimnames = list(Prediction = c("FALSE", 
    "TRUE"), Reference = c("FALSE", "TRUE")), class = "table"), 
        overall = c(Accuracy = 1, Kappa = 1, AccuracyLower = 0.823533088193035, 
        AccuracyUpper = 1, AccuracyNull = 0.631578947368421, 
        AccuracyPValue = 0.000161482422830051, McnemarPValue = NaN
        ), byClass = c(Sensitivity = 1, Specificity = 1, `Pos Pred Value` = 1, 
        `Neg Pred Value` = 1, Precision = 1, Recall = 1, F1 = 1, 
        Prevalence = 0.631578947368421, `Detection Rate` = 0.631578947368421, 
        `Detection Prevalence` = 0.631578947368421, `Balanced Accuracy` = 1
        ), mode = "sens_spec", dots = list()), class = "confusionMatrix"), 
    structure(list(positive = "FALSE", table = structure(c(12L, 
    0L, 0L, 7L), dim = c(2L, 2L), dimnames = list(Prediction = c("FALSE", 
    "TRUE"), Reference = c("FALSE", "TRUE")), class = "table"), 
        overall = c(Accuracy = 1, Kappa = 1, AccuracyLower = 0.823533088193035, 
        AccuracyUpper = 1, AccuracyNull = 0.631578947368421, 
        AccuracyPValue = 0.000161482422830051, McnemarPValue = NaN
        ), byClass = c(Sensitivity = 1, Specificity = 1, `Pos Pred Value` = 1, 
        `Neg Pred Value` = 1, Precision = 1, Recall = 1, F1 = 1, 
        Prevalence = 0.631578947368421, `Detection Rate` = 0.631578947368421, 
        `Detection Prevalence` = 0.631578947368421, `Balanced Accuracy` = 1
        ), mode = "sens_spec", dots = list()), class = "confusionMatrix"), 
    structure(list(positive = "FALSE", table = structure(c(12L, 
    0L, 0L, 7L), dim = c(2L, 2L), dimnames = list(Prediction = c("FALSE", 
    "TRUE"), Reference = c("FALSE", "TRUE")), class = "table"), 
        overall = c(Accuracy = 1, Kappa = 1, AccuracyLower = 0.823533088193035, 
        AccuracyUpper = 1, AccuracyNull = 0.631578947368421, 
        AccuracyPValue = 0.000161482422830051, McnemarPValue = NaN
        ), byClass = c(Sensitivity = 1, Specificity = 1, `Pos Pred Value` = 1, 
        `Neg Pred Value` = 1, Precision = 1, Recall = 1, F1 = 1, 
        Prevalence = 0.631578947368421, `Detection Rate` = 0.631578947368421, 
        `Detection Prevalence` = 0.631578947368421, `Balanced Accuracy` = 1
        ), mode = "sens_spec", dots = list()), class = "confusionMatrix"))
```

Iris obtained performance :

```
dput( iris_test[[3]])
list(structure(list(positive = NULL, table = structure(c(39L, 
11L, 0L, 0L, 49L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 48L), dim = c(3L, 3L), dimnames = list(
    Prediction = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"), Reference = c("setosa", 
    "versicolor", "virginica")), class = "table"), overall = c(Accuracy = 0.906666666666667, 
Kappa = 0.86, AccuracyLower = 0.848361468696352, AccuracyUpper = 0.948029827705522, 
AccuracyNull = 0.333333333333333, AccuracyPValue = 8.35658875188899e-49, 
McnemarPValue = NaN), byClass = structure(c(0.78, 0.98, 0.96, 
1, 0.87, 0.99, 1, 0.790322580645161, 0.979591836734694, 0.900900900900901, 
0.988636363636364, 0.98019801980198, 1, 0.790322580645161, 0.979591836734694, 
0.78, 0.98, 0.96, 0.876404494382023, 0.875, 0.96969696969697, 
0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.26, 
0.326666666666667, 0.32, 0.26, 0.413333333333333, 0.326666666666667, 
0.89, 0.925, 0.975), dim = c(3L, 11L), dimnames = list(c("Class: setosa", 
"Class: versicolor", "Class: virginica"), c("Sensitivity", "Specificity", 
"Pos Pred Value", "Neg Pred Value", "Precision", "Recall", "F1", 
"Prevalence", "Detection Rate", "Detection Prevalence", "Balanced Accuracy"
))), mode = "sens_spec", dots = list()), class = "confusionMatrix"), 
    structure(list(positive = NULL, table = structure(c(46L, 
    4L, 0L, 0L, 49L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 48L), dim = c(3L, 3L), dimnames = list(
        Prediction = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"), 
        Reference = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica")), class = "table"), 
        overall = c(Accuracy = 0.953333333333333, Kappa = 0.93, 
        AccuracyLower = 0.906214135012203, AccuracyUpper = 0.981034430365422, 
        AccuracyNull = 0.333333333333333, AccuracyPValue = 1.04274361946961e-58, 
        McnemarPValue = NaN), byClass = structure(c(0.92, 0.98, 
        0.96, 1, 0.94, 0.99, 1, 0.890909090909091, 0.979591836734694, 
        0.961538461538462, 0.989473684210526, 0.98019801980198, 
        1, 0.890909090909091, 0.979591836734694, 0.92, 0.98, 
        0.96, 0.958333333333333, 0.933333333333333, 0.96969696969697, 
        0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
        0.306666666666667, 0.326666666666667, 0.32, 0.306666666666667, 
        0.366666666666667, 0.326666666666667, 0.96, 0.96, 0.975
        ), dim = c(3L, 11L), dimnames = list(c("Class: setosa", 
        "Class: versicolor", "Class: virginica"), c("Sensitivity", 
        "Specificity", "Pos Pred Value", "Neg Pred Value", "Precision", 
        "Recall", "F1", "Prevalence", "Detection Rate", "Detection Prevalence", 
        "Balanced Accuracy"))), mode = "sens_spec", dots = list()), class = "confusionMatrix"), 
    structure(list(positive = NULL, table = structure(c(47L, 
    3L, 0L, 0L, 49L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 49L), dim = c(3L, 3L), dimnames = list(
        Prediction = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"), 
        Reference = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica")), class = "table"), 
        overall = c(Accuracy = 0.966666666666667, Kappa = 0.95, 
        AccuracyLower = 0.923927677462653, AccuracyUpper = 0.989089813531089, 
        AccuracyNull = 0.333333333333333, AccuracyPValue = 5.20551896612988e-62, 
        McnemarPValue = NaN), byClass = structure(c(0.94, 0.98, 
        0.98, 1, 0.96, 0.99, 1, 0.924528301886792, 0.98, 0.970873786407767, 
        0.989690721649484, 0.99, 1, 0.924528301886792, 0.98, 
        0.94, 0.98, 0.98, 0.969072164948454, 0.951456310679612, 
        0.98, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
        0.313333333333333, 0.326666666666667, 0.326666666666667, 
        0.313333333333333, 0.353333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
        0.97, 0.97, 0.985), dim = c(3L, 11L), dimnames = list(
            c("Class: setosa", "Class: versicolor", "Class: virginica"
            ), c("Sensitivity", "Specificity", "Pos Pred Value", 
            "Neg Pred Value", "Precision", "Recall", "F1", "Prevalence", 
            "Detection Rate", "Detection Prevalence", "Balanced Accuracy"
            ))), mode = "sens_spec", dots = list()), class = "confusionMatrix"))
```

Note that caret in `ballons case` not displaying `Statistics by Class:` because this dataset is binary.